# Javascript add option to select not doing anything after "if"

Tags: javascript, html

I am actually creating a little dropdown for every state for 2 countries (Canada and United States) to fit with an API i need to use for a customer. Actually, I have no issue getting the value of the "Country". However, as soon as I pass thru the if and for loops, I get no more informations released...

```
function stateByCountry(){
        var countryList = document.getElementById("country");
        var strCountry = countryList.options[countryList.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(strCountry);
        var stateSelect = document.getElementById("state");
        var caState = ["Alberta","British Columbia","Manitoba","New Brunswick","Newfoundland and Labrador","Nova Scotia","Northwest Territories","Nunavut","Ontario","Prince Edward Island","Quebec","Saskatchewan","Yukon"];
        var caStateValues = ["AB","BC","MB","NB","NL","NS","NT","NU","ON","PE","QC","SK","YT"];
        var usState = [];
        var usStateValues = [];
        if (strCountry == "CA") {
            for (var i = 0; i < caState.lenght; i++) {
                var state = caState[i];
                console.log(state);
                var stateValue = caStateValues[i];
                var stateOption = document.createElement("option");
                stateOption.textContent = state;
                stateOption.value = stateValue;
                stateSelect.appendChild(stateOption);
                console.log(state);
            }
        }
        if (strCountry == "US") {

        }
    }
```

Comment: could you also provide your html code?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: It seems that it's just a typo. You have `caState.lengHt` instead of `caState.length`. Fix it and tell us if it works then?

Comment: thanks a lot @NemanjaGlumac it was it :)